# Как задать путь к файлу относительно директории проекта?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Делаю просто web-приложение и встал вопрос, как указать путь к файлу, если он лежит внутри каталога проекта. Мой метод для записи текста в файл находится в App_Code/MyFolder/MyClass.cs а файл в свою очередь в папке, Files, которая на одном уровне с App_Code (Files/test.txt). Я пытался записать что-нибудь в файл следующим образом, но ничего не вышло.

```
File.WriteAllText("../../Files/test.txt", "Done");
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся. Я нашел немного другое решение:

```
File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Files/test.txt"), "Done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Простенький пример записи строки в файл.

```
string s = "Data for writing";
    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("FileName.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
    SW.Write(s);
    SW.Close();
```

И не забудьте подключить `using System.IO;`

Comment: Но куда мы пишем, где расположен этот FileName.txt? А если мне надо перейти на пару каталогов выше и еще в другую папку? И нельзя ли это сделать используя File.WriteAllText?

Comment: Если мы не указываем путь, то по умолчанию файл сохраняется в папку с проектом, путь -> папка c проектом -> bin - debug. Но если нужно указать путь, просто добавьте к названию файла нужный путь, а также не забудьте перед ковычками поставить знак собаки     
    `StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"d:\homework_C#\FileName.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));` или без собаки, но продублировать знаки слеша `StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("d:\\homework_C#\\FileName.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));`

Comment: Спасибо. Я использовал Httpcontext.